# How to correlate data from datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I have three datatables contains data as follows. I am posting small part of these datatables.

first datatable `dtnc`

```
Rnlidentifier(BSC)             Userlabel

3                         test_123
5                         fasi_123
6                         kira_123
```

second datatable `dtsite`

```
Rnlsupportingid             Sitename
{BSC 3,btsrdn 68}           VM_AO_3980
{BSC 3,btsrdn 69}           VM_AO_3981
{BSC 5,btsrdn 70}           VM_AO_3975
{BSC 5,btsrdn 71}           VM_AO_3976
{BSC 6,btsrdn 74}           VM_AO_3233
{BSC 6,btsrdn 75}           VM_AO_3234
```

third datatable `dtcell`

```
  cellmanager              cellname
    {BTS{BSC 3,btsrdn 68}}   Am_An_1000
    {BTS{BSC 3,btsrdn 68}}   Am_An_1001
    {BTS{BSC 6,btsrdn 74}}   Am_Al_1200
    {BTS{BSC 3,btsrdn 68}}   Am_An_1201
```

The relation is one row of `dtnc` contains many `dtsite` and one row of `dtsite` contains many `dtcell`.Now if i want to push the cell information in to database as `cellname,Sitename,Userlabel`  ,but i don't know how to correlate them. If i have only two datatables then i can use a dictionary and bind the information,but here i got stuck?Any one has any ideas??

Comment: how about using `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` ?

Comment: good idea,how to do that??

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321235/dictionary-with-object-as-value).

Comment: Can you post a small code for this question??

Comment: i am not getting how to proceed with this