# Read file and convert to dictionary with correct types

Tags: c#

I have a text file called "Exampel.txt". It has the following content.

```
{"eks": {"hel" : 0,"gain": [0,1,2,3,4,5, "htj"],"a": "bb" }, "slow": {"animals": {"sealion": "muuh", 1 : "blabla",},"eat": {"1": "straw",2: ["food", "insects", "bacon"]}}}
```

The content is never the same, but always in the above mentioned structure.
How can I read this as a dictionary in c#?

So I can use it like I do in python

Comment: This is a data notation format called Json and should be parsed with appropriate libraries. Json.NET is a widely used library that can map json data directly to classes. See http://json.net

Comment: Maybe you should include the python code you use for it or what you have tried in c#. The question as it stands now is: I have `input` and I want  *output*

Comment: This content isn't good for a single dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data seems to be in JSON format, you can deserialize same to have Directory.
Something like:

```
 Dictionary<string, object> values = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Here, your value type is not fixed, like it's sometimes JSONObject/ JSONArray/ String etc., in such case you should use Dictionary.

There are many examples in StackOverflow to get value, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24381795/1105291.

But is you know keys in the file and their data types, I would strongly recommend creating and use new Class instead of the object in Dictionary.

A Much better explanation is given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321505/1105291 by Nicolas Tyler.

Comment: How can i access the values afterwords ?
Like values["eks"] ?

Comment: Are you sure of the type of data? Will you have fixed keys?

Comment: @TobiasMøller, you may be interested in parsing [json as JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17842600/1997232) for this.