# when inner join in linq how can i select same column without using model class

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda

Actually ,I want to extract generic data from EF table without using models but unfortunately two columns with same name from different database crashed...

### Here is the query

```
var query = (from jbct in entities.Table1.AsEnumerable()
                             join p in entities.Table2.AsEnumerable() on jbct.perid equals p.id
                             select new
                             {
                              jbct.id,
                              p.id        
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

try use a dynamic name

```
        var query = (from jbct in entities.Table1.AsEnumerable()
                 join p in entities.Table2.AsEnumerable() on jbct.perid equals p.id
                 select new
                 {
                     Id1 = jbct.id,
                     Id2 = p.id

                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: okay thanks. I'll also try  this. I am able to return dynamic json results in my API without creating specific Models.I used genric collection class .
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>.

Comment: @Zuly you can create a dynamic object like this

Answer (score 0):

Now I've found now my solution to usie dictionary class

### [Dictionary with object as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321235/dictionary-with-object-as-value)

```
var query = (from jbct in entities.Table1.AsEnumerable() join p in entities.Table2.AsEnumerable() on jbct.perid equals p.id select new Dictionary<String, Object>
                         {
                             {"jbct_id", jbct.id},
                             {"p_id", p.id}}
).ToList();
```

---

Thanks

Comment: Still no idea what you're up to. I do know that because of the `AsEnumerable()` calls this is horribly inefficient code.

Comment: Should I use " IQueryable<Dictionary<string, Object>>" .. instead of  AsEnumerable()..